# Getting a buffer from a pointer

Tags: .net, pointers, intptr

This is the code I got the get the last error into a buffer, but I have no idea how to get the IntPtr converted to something I could read... I just get a long number.

```
/// Return Type: void
///pErrorCode: ABS_DWORD*
///ppErrorMessage: ABS_CHAR**
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("bsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "ABSGetLastErrorInfo", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void ABSGetLastErrorInfo(ref uint pErrorCode, ref System.IntPtr ppErrorMessage);
```

This is from the manual:

```
void ABSGetLastErrorInfo(
OUT ABS_DWORD *pErrorCode
OUT const ABS_CHAR **ppErrorMessage
)
```

Description Retrieves additional information about last BSAPI error, which occurred in the current thread.

ppErrorMessage On output this is set to point to a buffer containing zero-terminated
string with textual message.

If no message is provided, it points to empty string so the caller does
not need check it for NULL.

The buffer is managed by BSAPI; do not use ABSFree to release it.
Note that the buffer is valid only until other BSAPI call is performed
in the same thread. After the next call, the buffer may be released or
reused by BSAPI. If you need to remember the message, you have to
copy it into your own buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define as

```
 public static extern void ABSGetLastErrorInfo(ref uint pErrorCode, StringBuilder ppErrorMessage);
```

`StringBuilder` is used for Output strings. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).

> If the string parameter can be input
>   and/or output, then use the
>   System.StringBuilder type. The
>   StringBuilder type is a useful class
>   library type that helps you build
>   strings efficiently, and it happens to
>   be great for passing buffers to native
>   functions that the functions fill with
>   string data on your behalf. Once the
>   function call has returned, you need
>   only call ToString on the
>   StringBuilder object to get a String
>   object.

---

### UPDATE

As Jim Kindly mentioned, define the `StringBuilder` as ref.

```
public static extern void ABSGetLastErrorInfo(ref uint pErrorCode, ref StringBuilder ppErrorMessage);
```

Comment: when I call it like this 
            Dim Code As UInteger
            Dim errorInfo As StringBuilder = Nothing
            ABSGetLastErrorInfo(Code, errorInfo)
the application crashes with no error.

Comment: No, create a new stringbuilder and pass it to the function. After the call, stringbuilder should have your string returned.

Comment: Same results :( still crashing

Comment: I do believe that `StringBuilder` should be passed by reference. `ref StringBuilder ppErrorMessage`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then make it `ref IntPtr ppErrorMessage`, and when you get the value back call `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx

Comment: Jim, can you enter a post so it can be accepted. It is not fair for my answer to be accepted.

Comment: @Ezi: Go ahead and accept @Aliostad's answer. He provided the idea. I just refined it.